# How to share a custom post/video to Instagram from my XSLT web application?

Tags: xslt, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

What is the correct method to share something to Instagram from my XSLT web application? Eg: Users must be able to share the posts/videos on my web application to Instagram, Facebook, Twitter etc.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/